# How to open cups in debian squeeze to all clients

Tags: debian, cups

The standard CUPS configuration on debian squeeze allows only access from localhost.

I would like to allow all LAN users the same permissions. The LAN is behind a secured router. Access to the eb interface and ürinting and full job control is the minimal that all clients should be able to do without login.

What do I need to change and where in my cups configuration?

---

Edit

For others looking for an answer, try this howto

http://dev.shyd.de/2011/03/debian-printserver-scanserver-hplip-cups-sane/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a simple way to do it over the browser.

Just went to http://localhost:631 and then to administration. On the right side there are several options, I activated these and restarted:

- Share printers connected to this system
- Allow printing from the Internet
- Advertise web interface
- Allow remote administration
- Allow users to cancel any job (not just their own)

Now I can go to the cups server of the machine from any other browser on the lan:

http://cupsmachine:631

And also printing from other machines works.

Comment: Worked for me on debian wheezy.